# What's the best way to send an array through Datagram Packets?

Tags: java, arrays, datagram

Say I had a String: `Hello!` I have to do all this:

1. Convert string into byte array
2. Send byte array
3. Convert it back to a string (for later use)

This is my code...

```
//Sender
String send = "Hello!";
byte[] data = send.getBytes();
DatagramPacket packetOut = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length); //send blah blah

//Receiver
//blah blah receive it
String receive = new String(packetIn.getData()); //convert it back
```

What's a quick and elegant way to do this for an array of integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an int[] you can serialize using ObjectOutputStream but a faster way might be to use a ByteBuffer.

```
public static byte[] intsToBytes(int[] ints) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(ints.length * 4);
    IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();
    for (int i : ints) ib.put(i);
    return bb.array();
}

public static int[] bytesToInts(byte[] bytes) {
    int[] ints = new int[bytes.length / 4];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asIntBuffer().get(ints);
    return ints;
}
```

Comment: Why do you multiply the integer array length by 4? EDIT: Because a byte is 8 bits for every 32 bit int? Just to make sure a float would be multiplied by 4 and long would be * 8?

Comment: I assume you want to keep all 4 bytes (4 * 8 bits) of the 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this way is elegant but it will be quick. Use GSON library to convert array of Integers to String, and convert from String to Integer array back.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
...

Gson gson = new Gson();

List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3); 

//Sender
String send = gson.toJson(list);
byte[] data = send.getBytes();
DatagramPacket packetOut = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length); //send blah blah

//Receiver
//blah blah receive it
String receive = new String(packetIn.getData()); //convert it back

Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Integer>(){}.getType();
List<Integer> list = gson.fromJson(receive, listType);
```

Gson has low performance but it justifies quick usage .if you use not complicated objects like `java.util.List` - will be good.

You can get GSON jar from there: [link: gson 1.7](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson17jar.htm)

By the way with GSON you can convert any type of Object to String and vice versa.